# Can I execute another users transaction if I have their typedData and signature from the signedTypeData?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, signature, message

I have `typedData` from a user and their signature:

```
 const signature = await signedTypeData(typedData.domain, typedData.types, typedData.value);
```

Can someone explain to me why I cannot execute their signed type data on their behalf? Any ideas how to do it? Could someone point me into some material about how this is done normally via messages? eg Matcha has this. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signed transaction and signed typed data are two different things. They solve two different problems for two different reasons.

You can sign a transaction without actually sending it, and that object can be given to someone/something else and it can be sent to the blockchain by anyone if they are willing to pay for the gas. The more usual pattern is to sign and send in one move but it doesn't necessarily have to be that way. Have a look over here for inspiration: https://medium.com/finnovate-io/how-do-i-sign-transactions-with-web3-f90a853904a2

EIP-712, Signed Typed Data is for a different purpose.

There are many cases where an off-chain signature is useful. For example, to convince a website that you are the owner of a certain address. Web3 allows the signing of a message.

```
message: {
  myAddress: 0x123...
}
```

A signature is a bytes string. Given the message and the signature, the signer address is recovered with `ecrecover`. So ... it is possible to confirm that the above example was actually signed by `0x123` if the message + signature recovers `0x123`. Any other result means someone else signed it - it's a fake.

Messages are usually reduced to a hash. Receivers hash the message, then recover the address from the hash + signature, but since the user is signing a hash, they really don't know what they're signing. MetaMask (etc) display meaningless hex code.

EIP-712 helps the user know what they're signing.

The message is displayed for them much like above, with key/value pairs so they can actually read it. The messages are formatted with a schema ("Typed" messages) that lays out the fields in the messeages. EIP-712 hashes it a certain way and and methods like "signTypedData" take a strongly typed message object, hash it and sign it the right way. EIP-712 also prescribes the process for recovering the address, and even ensures that the signed message is only usable by the intended recipient.

The recipient will get:

```
message: {
  keys: values
}
signature: bytes
```

... and they will be able to determine who signed it.

Here's the thing. Knowing who signed the message doesn't entitle them to impersonate the signer in any way. The normal security rules still apply. `msg.sender` is still the entity that *sent* the transaction to the blockchain. There are patterns that combine all of this. For example, gasless (meta) transactions.

1. User signs a message that describes their intent.
2. User sends the message and the signature to a relay.
3. Relay checks the signature and, if willing to, sends the transaction to a contract and pays for gas. This is a specially crafted transaction that contains the original message that was signed and the signature.
4. The contract checks the relay's permission to send meta transactions.
5. The contract unpacks the message and the signature.
6. The contract determines who signed the original message and uses that instead of `msg.sender` (because `msg.sender` is a relay and not who signed the original message). Support for this sleight of hand must be baked into the contract, for example openzeppline/contracts/metatx/EIP712Context. It's not something that is backwards compatible with contracts that don't know how to unpack meta transactions.

"Message" and "transaction" are different in most contexts, so the terms are used deliberately. "`msg.sender`" is a bit of misnomer that should be taken to mean "transaction sender".

Hope it helps.